# Can a server initiate web socket connection to the client (how does webpack-dev-server sends updates)?

Tags: websocket, webpack, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

I am wondering if the server can initiate the connection to the client after it has served ordinary html file via GET request?

More specifically I have set up webpack development server and all browser refresh after I change files work, but I cannot find any bootstrapping in the client. I see there are no special embedded script tags or any inline script or anything that can trigger the communication, yet I get the web socket in my network tab. Maybe I just got it all wrong and there is some trigger that I cannot find?

Comment: No. The server can't initiate a connection. The client isn't listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment it's not possible to initiate the web-scoket connection from the server and I have managed to figure out what happens with the webpack-dev-server.

It injects a special module (or rather a lot of them) and calls it during the initialization right before your entry point is executed.

```js
webpackJsonp([1],{


/***/ 1:
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// Here is the module that connects to the dev-server
__webpack_require__("./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http:/localhost:8080");

// This is your entry point
module.exports = __webpack_require__("./Source/main.ts");

}

},[1]);
```

P.S. I have used `webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()` to get the proper names for the modueles instead of numbers to understand what's going on.